# Algorithm to find the shortest connection between two points on a series of cylinder/cone segements & find a specific point on the connection

Tags: algorithm, math, 3d, geometry, computational-geometry

I have a series of cylinder segments and circular cone segments (cone frustums). The center axes of the cylinder and cone segments are identical with the Z-axis. All segment dimensions (radius, height, position on the z-axis) are given.

[image]

Furthermore two points *P1(x1,y1,z1)* and *P2(x2,y2,z2)* are given. These points lie on the surface of different cylinder/cone segments.

Let's name the curve on the surface of the series of cylinder/cone segments which is the shortest connection between the two points *P1* and *P2* with the letter *C*.

Also given is a length *L*. *L* is always smaller than the total length of the curve *C*.

I am looking for an algorithm to calculate the *(x,y,z)* coordinates of a new point *V* which lies on *C* at the distance *L* from *P1* i.e. the curve length between *P1* and *V* should be *L*.

My plan is to first calculate the points where *C* crosses from one cylinder/cone segment to the next. Then I would have the individual curves in each cylinder/cone segment as well as their lengths. Then I can find out in which cylinder/cone segment *V* lies and calculate the *(x,y,z)* coordinates of *V*.

The question is how do I find the crossing points?

(Or is my plan not ideal, too complex? Is there a simpler, more elegant overall approach?)

I would greatly appreciate any guidance to this problem.

Comment: You can treat cylinders as a special case of cone so you need a formula describing the shortest path between two points on the surface of an arbitrary cone. Then you could do some gradient descent algorithm to find the optimum positions of the 'crossing points'. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140636/what-is-the-shortest-path-equation-between-2-points-on-a-cone

Comment: Thanks. I know already the article on math.stackexchange.com. Very helpful. However the question is how to find the 'crossing points'. Could you please explain in more detail what you mean with "some gradient descent algorithm to find the optimum positions of the 'crossing points'". Thank you.

Comment: If you define each crossing point as X_i = (r_i, theta_i, z_i) then r_i and z_i are known, you just need theta_i. Define Distance function D(theta_1, ..., ,theta_n) for n crossing points then calculate GradD(theta_1, ..., ,theta_n) for gradient descent. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent

Comment: 1) Given the position of the three crossing points (maybe parametrised by the angle that gives their position on the circle they're in), get a formula for the shortest path from P1 to P2 that passes through these three crossing points. 2) Once you have this formula, you "just" need to find the value of the three parameters to minimise it. Gradient descent is probably overkill for this, you can probably get three explicit formulae by analysing the function. If you can't get explicit formulae, then gradient descent is a possibility. Or use scipy.optimise or something.

Comment: 3) Now you've figured out the positions of the three crossing points. Calculate the distance d1 from P1 to the first crossing point, d2 from first crossing point to second crossing point, etc. 4) Find whether L is in [0, d1] or [d1, d1+d2] or [d1+d2,d1+d2+d3] or [d1+d2+d3, d1+d2+d3+d4]. 5) Get a formula for point V.

Comment: Sure, if you can solve GradD = 0 analytically, then great but I think the equations would become unmanageable quickly as n increases.

Answer (score 0):

my intuition tells me the curve `C` will lie on plane (the same one as `P1,P2` line lies) so:

1. **find the plane**

   where `P1,P2,P3` lies where `P3'` is point on (infinite) line `P1,P2` where `y=0` or `x=0` which s point that crosses the center axis (z) so:

   ```
   P3 = vec3(0,0,P3'.z)
   ```

   the plane can be defined by point (any from `P1,P2,P3`) and normal `N`:

   ```
   N = cross(P2-P1,P3-P2)
   ```
2. **for each cone edge (circle) compute intersection with the plane `Vc[]`**

   use only points closer to `P1,P2` line this should give you the crossing points `Vc[]`.
3. **compute `C` length `lc[]` at each crossing point**

   its just adding up line segment lengths.
4. **linear or binary search `lc[]` to select segmen where wanted `V` lies**

   for small number of segments use linear and for many segments use binary search. Just find `i` where:

   ```
   (lc[i]<=l) AND (lc[i+1]>=l)
   ```
5. **linerly interpolate your `V`**

   ```
   V0 = Vc[i]
   V1 = Vc[i+1]
   l0 = lc[i]
   l1 = lc[i+1]
   l  = wanted length
   V = V0+(V1-V0)*(l-l0)/(l1-l0)
   ```

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure if I understand your answer correctly. Are you seeing C as a series of line segments? This is not the case. C is a series of curves which lie either on the surface of a cylinder or the surface of a cone. These are not straight line segments.

Comment: h is the height of this object.

Comment: @AliAli if you are looking from "inside the plane" they (projected as) lines but you're right for the arclength computation you need to integrate the length instead of using simple line length

Answer (score -1):

I have idea like this.

This problem is related to 3d geometry.
More detail, the intersection of plane and cone, cylinder.
The last point on Z axis is Q(0,0,h).
The middle point on Z axis is M(0,0,h/2)

Calculate the function of plane that has 3 points such as P1,P2 and M.
Calculate the intersection points of every edge of cones and cylinder.

This intersection points are the C series and intersection line is the shortest path from P1 to P2.

It is possible to calculate the function of plane, cone and cylinder given conditions.

Comment: Thanks. I am not quite understand what 'h' is respectively where Q and M are located. Could you please explain?

Comment: I do not understand why the intersections of the cylinder/cone edge circle with the plane through P1, P2, M give the crossing points which I am looking for. Could you please explain more? Thanks.